# Ring isomorphism is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an elementary proof showing that a ring isomorphism is an equivalence relation? Isomorphism is defined as usually is, a bijective homomorphism $\phi$. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A relation $R$ is an equivalence relation if it is:

1. reflexive, i.e. $xRx$ for all $x$
2. symmetric, i.e. if $xRy$ then $yRx$
3. transitive, i.e. if $xRy$ and $yRz$ then $xRz$

You need to prove all three properties.

Comment: @TyrellBanks In this case, swap "$R$" with " is isomorphic to ", and you'll have a straight-forward list of things you need to check.

Comment: Remember the identity function can be defined on any ring and is always an isomorphism. This checks 1.

Comment: For 2 show that an isomorphism between $x$ and $y$ has a bijective inverse which can also be an isomorphism. Therefore showing symmetry.